# Why await MethodName is working different from await Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

you will see a console app codes below. There are two situations I tried. In the first case, I commented await GetProducts() line. In this case, output is:

Start Time: 13:20:30
Job started...
Finish Time: 13:20:30
Job finished...

In second case, I opened await GetProducts line and commented await Task.Run...lines. In this case, output is:

Start Time: 13:19:33
Job started...
Job finished...
Finish Time: 13:19:43

Here are the code lines...What is the difference?
Thanks...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task x = LoadProductsAsync();

        Console.Read();
    }


    private static async Task LoadProductsAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start Time: "  + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        //await GetProducts();

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            GetProducts();
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Finish Time: " + DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
    }

    private static Task<List<Product>> GetProducts()
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => GetProductsByCategory()
        );
    }

    private static List<Product> GetProductsByCategory()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Job started...");

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

        Console.WriteLine("Job finished...");

        return new List<Product>();

    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to read http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html and http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html.

Comment: I think, my version would have been very useful for the web application. Think about a web page that loads large data set from database in form_load method. In this case, the page waits for database operation. But in my version, a page can be displayed without getting dataset. Am I right?

Comment: No, you are not right. Page will only be sent out when the data is fetched. `async` is used in ASP.NET [for a different reason](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15190112/11683).

Answer (score 6):

This is the problem:

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    GetProducts();
});
```

You're not waiting for the task returned by `GetProducts()` to complete - you're just waiting for the immediate `GetProducts()` method call to complete.

The simplest fix to that is to use a method group conversion instead, and call [`Task.Run<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194918(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
await Task.Run(GetProducts);
```

Then the task returned by `Task.Run` will be a proxy task for the task returned by `GetProducts()`, so the `await` expression won't complete until `GetProducts` has really finished.

Comment: I think, my version would have been very useful for the web application. Think about a web page that loads large data set from database in form_load method. In this case, the page waits for database operation. But in my version, a page can be displayed without getting dataset. Am I right?

Comment: @qwerty: Not really - you don't have anywhere for the results to end up. If you want to load the data after the page, you'd do that with Javascript in the client.

Answer (score -2):

Change your code to snnipet below. And your code will be the same.

```
await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        GetProductsByCategory();
    });
```

Your last code was like (you run task in task):

```
await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () => GetProductsByCategory()
        );
    });
```